# Is java 8 no longer lts?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I was downloading java jdk and in the list https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html it shows LTS only in front of java 11. But java 8 was LTS as I know and I also searched on wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history and it shows java 8 as LTS version which will be supported untill 2030. So, does that mean java 8 is no longer a LTS version.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html

Comment: By the way why do you bother about long term support? We can still use java8, but they don't release updates that't it.

Comment: The term LTS was introduced with Java 11 (or technically with Java 9), before Java 9, all Java versions had a support policy that resulted in years (if not decades) of support. That changed with the new fast release cycle of Java.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's still a LTS since extended support will be provided till 2030. You can check the official Oracle Java Roadmap.

Comment: https://endoflife.date/java

Answer (score 2):

For personal use, you can continue to get public updates from Oracle, but if you are a commercial user, make sure you have the commercial license if you want to use Oracle Java.

This is the reason that many commercial projects including my own rushed to switch to OpenJDK or Aws Corretto before the deadline to not violate Oracle's license. Fortunately, RedHat, which is main force behind OpenJDK communiy has committed to support OpenJDK Java 8 until 2026.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013

AWS has also made the same committment for Corretto 8.
https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are more interested in OpenJDK rather than Oracle JDK since the last *public* update of Oracle JDK 8 was in 2019. Oracle provides Java 8 updates only for Oracle customers. However, OpenJDK 8 is still available and it's being maintained by RedHat. RedHat [promises](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013) that it's going to support Java 8 until **May 2026**.

Comment: According to https://endoflife.date/java - Java 8 is supported under 2030

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: you mean *November 2026*?

Comment: @Orphans: I thinks that's for the Oracle version ...